# Passenger on bitnami - can't access app root, all other routes working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I created a bitnami instance on AWS, and uploaded my rails application at - 
/home/bitnami/my_app

I added the following to my virtual hosts -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin test@test.com
  DocumentRoot "/home/bitnami/my_app/public"
  <Directory /home/bitnami/my_app/public>
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
</Directory>
  RailsEnv production
  ServerName www.my_app.com
  ErrorLog "logs/my_app.com-error_log"
  CustomLog "logs/my_app.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Inside the application routes.rb, I have -

root :to => "pages#home"

I can access all the routes in the application, i.e. if I go to www.my_app.com/signin, it works.

However, trying to access root - i.e. www.my_app.com gives 404 error.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled Passenger in the Apache configuration? The guide below may help:

http://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Phusion_Passenger

Comment: Thanks. I found out that there was an error while fetching records on my home page. It is weird that apache chose to show 404 instead of some other error in this case. Anyways, found this out after looking at apache error_log.